# I am trying to make a SQL query of Update in python but it is giving error

Tags: python, mysql

```py
comnd = ("UPDATE booking SET check_out_time = " + (datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))+ " WHERE Contact_no = "+ str(contact_number_en.get())
        )
```

Error :- **mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':00 WHERE Contact_no = 9827355876' at line 1**

> How can I do this to make a single query of SQL ?

Comment: Because the resulting string is missing quotes. **However,** stop using string concat to build SQL queries. Research parametrized queries.

Comment: I had asked a normal question why are u down voting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a prepared statement here, e.g.

```py
sql = "UPDATE booking SET check_out_time = %s WHERE Contact_no = %s"
vals = (datetime.now(), contact_number_en.get())
cursor.execute(sql, vals)
```